# Add rule lifecycle each object in bucket storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm a newbie with Google Cloud Platform Product, I would like to know. It's possible to assign a rule lifetime cycle. Which specific object in my bucket.

```
├── Bucket
    ├── object_a  (with rule)
    └── object_b  (without rule)
```

I have to read a document, Which a rule has been added to the bucket. Then effect to whole object in bucket. I can't avoid this one.

So is it possible to add rule for each object in the the bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.  As you've seen from the documentation, rules apply to entire buckets[1].  You can create different buckets with different rules, if you want[2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#behavior
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets